# How to create an index for a 'TEXT' column in a MySQL database by means of JPA/Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, indexing, hql

I need to create an index for a 'TEXT' column in a MySQL database. I can't do it using this annotation

```
@Table(name = "table1", indexes = @Index(name = "ix_table1_column1", columnList = "column1"))
```

as MySQL can only index the first N characters of the 'TEXT' column, so I get this kind of exception:

```
BLOB/TEXT column 'column1' used in key specification without a key length
```

(obviously I don't get this exception if I change the type of the column from 'TEXT' to 'VARCHAR(255)')

I've tried to create an index via a custom HQL query by adding a method to the repository:

```
@Query("create index ix_table1_column1 on Table1Entity(column1(255))") 
void createIndex();
```

but with no success, as I get this kind of exceptions:

```
unexpected token: create near line 1, column 1 [create index create index ix_table1_column1 on Table1Entity(column1(255))]
```

(looks like there's no 'create index' command in HQL)

However, with the 'TEXT' type of column1, I'm able to create an index via this statement in the database where I just add a character limit to the name of the column:

```
create index ix_table1_column1 on schema1.table1(column1(255));
```

Is there a way to do this via an annotation of via an HQL custom query?

Comment: `@Column(length = 255)`

Comment: Tried that, didn't help

Comment: "create index create index" -- sounds like Hibernate is supplying "create index" so your specifying it is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the command:

```
create index ix_table1_column1 on schema1.table1(column1(255))
```

in a `.sql` file, and then use the standard JPA property `jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source` to tell Hibernate where to find it.

Comment: Hey @Gavin, thank you so much for the idea, I did it in a slightly different way, I just added the 'spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql', 'spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true', and 'spring.sql.init.mode=always' parameters to my application.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Let's dig deeper into what you plan to do with that index.

- Exact match on long Text?  This seems unlikely application.
- Be happy with checking just the beginning of the text?  Well, the "prefix" index may or may not help performance.  Example:  `WHERE col LIKE 'Start%'`
- Looking for something in the middle of the Text?  Well, `col LIKE '%abc%'` will not use the index and will be slow.
- Hoping to search for a "word" in the Text?  That begs for a `FULLTEXT` index and the construct `SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST("word" IN BOOLEAN MODE)` -- This is fast and efficient, but has limitations.

Comment: Hi @Rick, thank you for your comment, the thing is, it’s a coding project at school where I need to program an application according to a certain specification. And in this specification, it’s explicitly stated that the column where I need this index must be of Text type. You’re absolutely right, there’s no need to find an exact match on long Text, and the string values that are supposed to be stored in that column are not that long at all. So, the easiest way to solve the problem would be to change the type from Text to Varchar, but I just can’t deviate from the specification that I was given

Comment: I have choice words to say about teaching prefix indexing to beginners.  It is one of the least useful constructs in MySQL.  There are many other things to fill the classroom time with.  [Feel free to sho the teacher this Comment.]